# How to remove quotation marks (and other marks)?

Tags: python, string, brackets, quotation-marks

Is there any way to avoid printing out data (like quotations marks, brackets, commas and other important matematical symbols) when printing from a variable?

```
int1 = random.randint(1,100)
int2 = random.randint(1,100)
q1 = "What is", int1, "+", int2, "?"
answer = int(raw_input(q1))
```

The code above prints this:

```
('What is', 75, '+', 74, '? ')149
```

The proper way of printing the above would supposedly be this:

```
What is 75 + 74? 149
```

Comment: `q1` is a tuple. If you wanted to make a string use `+` to concatenate and explicitly convert numbers to string using `str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clearest syntax I believe would be the one that separates the constant string from the variables:

```
print "What is %d + %d?" % (int1, int2)
```

Answer (score 3):

The "proper way" is to use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
q1 = "What is {0} + {1}? ".format(int1, int2)
answer = int(raw_input(q1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
q1 = "What is" +  str(int1) +  "+" + str(int2) + "?"
```

or

```
' '.join([str(x) for x in q1])
```